# Removing empty space above vaadin-date-picker element

Tags: polymer, vaadin

I want to remove the empty space above the vaadin-date-picker element.

I know that it uses some mixins, but could you please help me with code to change display to "none"?

Here is its documentation:
https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-date-picker#docs

[image]

Comment: porpably i don't get it. What you want to do? if you dont want to display label, then set `label=""`

Comment: I updated the post. I mean the placeholder which is above this vaadin-date-picker element.

Comment: what i found out is a little bit against polymer, because this is not said anywhere in documentation of the elements, but i found out in code that you can set display: none to mixin `--paper-font-caption` . So : 
`vaadin-date-picker {
  --paper-font-caption: {
    display: none;
  }
}`
i am not sure if this is what you were looking for

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot with it. Now it's much better. Thank you.

Ok, after all it's like this:
    vaadin-date-picker {
        --paper-font-caption: { display: none; };
        --paper-input-container: { padding-top: 0px;}
      }

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský You can answer this question if you want, so if someone searches in the future, he will find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future searches and for everyone wondering how to completely hide label so it won't have so big height.

Editing mixin --paper-font-caption is needed. 
`Vaadin-date-picker` is using `paper-input-container` which has only 1 mixin applied and it's `--paper-font-caption`.

So this solution works for all elements using `paper-input` or `paper-input-container`.

**example:**

```
vaadin-date-picker {
  --paper-font-caption: {
    display: none;
  }
  --paper-input-container: {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

**BEWARE** - This solution might not work in the future. This is not written anywhere in documentation or so. I just found it in code.

If anyone in the future founds this is not working, i can edit this and make another solution

Comment: Could you please also add: --paper-input-container: { padding-top: 0px;} to the answer?